# How to represent a link dynamically in php?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0)   
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { 
        echo '<br /><br />Name: ' .$row['name'];
        echo '<br /><br />Contact Number: ' .$row['cont'];
        echo '<br /><br />Email ID: ' .$row['email'];
        echo "<br /><br /><a href='viewdtl.php' target='_blank'>View details</a>";  
        echo "<br /><hr />"; 
   }
   }
else
{
    echo "0 records found";
}
$stmt->close(); 
?>
```

This code runs just fine but with two problems.. The else part `0 records found` always shows which i want to print after the search get placed and the link .. i can't click on it.. how can i print the link here ?  [image: Added the screenshot]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your Inspect Element and the unclickable link, thanks

Comment: `$result->num_rows > 0` must be without the quotes

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What is not working exactly?

Comment: the link i m giving is not clickable .. i cant click on it

Comment: You mean this link: `<a href='viewdtl.php' target='_blank'>View details</a>`? Does viewdtl.php exist? You also need to pass the ID of the user (i.e. `viewdtl.php?id=1`

Comment: What script does `viewdtl.php` contain?

Comment: yeah i knw i ll give the id later but firstly it's not clickable at all ..

Comment: So, when you click on 'View details', nothing happens? No refresh/reload, no redirect, absolutely nothing? because you're link seems to be fine. And your link has nothing to do with the PHP code (the difference between serverside & client side)

Comment: yes nothing happens.. no refresh no reload no redirection no hover nothing

Comment: It has something to do with your computer or browser, because here it's working fine

Comment: what !!!! ... why it's not working here then

Comment: Fix the error of spacer.gif, maybe it works, but normally it does'nt should make a difference for the rest of the HTML

Comment: Tht's not the problem :( :( ..

Comment: i think i have a problem in my css .. i removed the css now the link is working fine